# Error when running TensorBox train.py

Tags: python, linux, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have configured TensorBox on my 64-bit GPU running Ubuntu 14.04. TensorFlow is set up on the machine and is completely functional.

When I run

```
python train.py --hypes hypes/lstm_rezoom.json --gpu 0 --logdir output
```

within the TensorBox directory - which should begin retraining the network on the specified directory of data - I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 85, in __call__
ret = func(*args)
  File "train.py", line 390, in log_image
rnn_len=H['rnn_len'])[0]
  File "~/tensorbox/utils/train_utils.py", line 127, in add_rectangles
    from stitch_wrapper import stitch_rects
ImportError: ~/tensorbox/utils/stitch_wrapper.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Internal: Failed to run py callback pyfunc_1: see error log.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Internal: Failed to run py callback pyfunc_1: see error log.
         [[Node: PyFunc_1 = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fifo_queue_1_DequeueMany, strided_slice_12, strided_slice_13, Variable/read, PyFunc_1/input_4)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Internal: Failed to run py callback pyfunc_1: see error log.
         [[Node: PyFunc_1 = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fifo_queue_1_DequeueMany, strided_slice_12, strided_slice_13, Variable/read, PyFunc_1/input_4)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 85, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
  File "train.py", line 390, in log_image
    rnn_len=H['rnn_len'])[0]
  File "~/tensorbox/utils/train_utils.py", line 127, in add_rectangles
    from stitch_wrapper import stitch_rects
ImportError: ~/tensorbox/utils/stitch_wrapper.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Internal: Failed to run py callback pyfunc_0: see error log.
W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:294] _0_fifo_queue: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:294] _1_fifo_queue_1: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 549, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 546, in main
    train(H, test_images=[])
  File "train.py", line 504, in train
    ], feed_dict=lr_feed)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to run py callback pyfunc_1: see error log.
         [[Node: PyFunc_1 = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fifo_queue_1_DequeueMany, strided_slice_12, strided_slice_13, Variable/read, PyFunc_1/input_4)]]

Caused by op u'PyFunc_1', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 549, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 546, in main
    train(H, test_images=[])
  File "train.py", line 448, in train
    smooth_op, global_step, learning_rate) = build(H, q)
  File "train.py", line 402, in build
    [tf.float32])
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 192, in py_func
    input=inp, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_script_ops.py", line 40, in _py_func
    name=name)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InternalError (see above for traceback): Failed to run py callback pyfunc_1: see error log.
         [[Node: PyFunc_1 = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fifo_queue_1_DequeueMany, strided_slice_12, strided_slice_13, Variable/read, PyFunc_1/input_4)]]
```

I can't seem to figure out the problem. I've checked that the files it's accessing (e.g. .so) are in fact in the correct directory path, and I've tried some modifications of the train.py file itself that were suggested on other help pages (ex. changing
`state_is_tuple`
on lines 39 and 41 to False) - but they don't seem to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Did you ever make headway on this problem?